# Mongoid or/any_of unexpected behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having an issue with mongoid `any_of`. I'm trying to find objects that have either one field > 0, or another one > 0. My query is :

```
Model.any_of(best_friend_method.gt => 0, method.gt => 0).desc(best_friend_method, method)
```

It is "translated" in :

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"$or"=>[{:best_friends_lc_sum=>{"$gt"=>0}, :lc_sum=>{"$gt"=>0}}]},
  options:  {:sort=>[[:best_friends_lc_sum, :desc], [:lc_sum, :desc]]},
  class:    FbAlbum,
  embedded: false>
```

As I understand it, this is what I want. But it only returns me 6 results. `Model.where(:best_friends_lc_sum.gt => 0).count` returns me 6 results too, but `Model.where(:lc_sum.gt => 0).count` returns me ~850 objects.

I expect my query to return the union of those two : is a mongoid/mongodb error, or am I doing something wrong ?

FYI : mongoid 2.4.5, mongodb 2.0.2, rails 3.1.3

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you querying the right attributes? It seems like you are using best_friend_method and method in the query but your criteria is best_friends_lc_sum and lc_sum.

Comment: Yes, it is wanted. I have the same set of attributes but with `lct` instead of `lc`. My method is supposed to look up the args given, and choose according to those which attributes (the lct ones or the lc ones) will be used for the query

Comment: I'm sorry ksol, without more information it seems like the query being constructed by mongoid is the correct one but I am confused about the data model and what is in those collections. If you run the query against mongo directly does it give you what you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you pass only one args and not 2 args. So it's like you have no `$or` usage.

Try :

```
Model.any_of({best_friend_method.gt => 0}, {method.gt => 0}).desc(best_friend_method, method)
```

In this case the Criteria become :

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"$or"=>[{:best_friends_lc_sum=>{"$gt"=>0}}, {:lc_sum=>{"$gt"=>0}}]},
  options:  {:sort=>[[:best_friends_lc_sum, :desc], [:lc_sum, :desc]]},
  class:    FbAlbum,
  embedded: false>
```

Sometime the usage of `{}` is mandatory to separate different hash.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone...In Mongoid 3, the Origin gem provides the syntax for querying. Here is the [list of methods that you can use to write your Mongoid 3 queries](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html). Among those methods is the `or` method which allows you to perform an `$or` query:

```
# Mongoid query:
Model.or(
  { name: "Martin" }, { name: "Dave" }
)

# resulting MongoDB query:
{
  "$or" => [
    { "name" => "Martin" }, { "name" => "Dave" }
  ]
}
```

Using the OP's original example, it can be rewritten as:

```
Model.or(
  { best_friend_method.gt => 0 },
  { method.gt => 0 }
).order_by(
  best_friend_method,
  method
)
```

At least one of the hashes passed to the `or` method must match in order for a record to be returned.